# Concurrent ModificationException

Tags: java

I have a piece of code and i am not sure why i am getting the concurrentModificationException

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CreateList{
    List<Integer> nestedList;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Nested List");
        CreateList obj = new CreateList();
        System.out.println(obj.createNestedList(sc.next()));
    }
    public List<Integer> createNestedList(String str){
        List<Object> aux = new LinkedList<Object>();
        nestedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for(int itr=0; itr<str.length();itr++){
            char c = str.charAt(itr);
            if(c != ']' && c != ',')
            aux.add(c);
            else if(c == ']'){
                Object o = aux.subList(aux.lastIndexOf('[')+1,aux.size());
                aux = aux.subList(0,aux.lastIndexOf('['));
                aux.add(o);// THIS LINE IS THROWING THE EXCEPTION
                System.out.println(o);
                System.out.println(aux);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(aux);
        return nestedList;
    }
}
```

There is no thread using this code other then the main thread. Any idea what am i missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is the use of subLists.  Specifically

```
aux = aux.subList(0,aux.lastIndexOf('['));
```

And then later

```
aux.add(o);// THIS LINE IS THROWING THE EXCEPTION
```

This changes the size of the sublist vs the size of the original list.

The javadoc of sublist says:

> The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)

The sublist instance returned by `.subList()` throws an exception if the modcounts of the sublist vs the original list differ.

The solution is to make a new list using the elements from the sublist

```
aux = new LinkedList<>(aux.subList(0,aux.lastIndexOf('[')));
```

Comment: Would this work `aux = new LinkedList<Object>(aux.subList(0, aux.lastIndexOf('[')));`?

Comment: @JasonSperske yes infact I was just putting that in my edited answer

Comment: What dkatzel shows is correct. don't use the same object for the sublist.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create another list instead of getting a sublist and adding a sublist to it.

try something like this instead:

```
List<T> list = new LinkedList<T>(someList.subList(0,n));
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use a list iterator if you intend to modify the list while iterating.

```
List<Object> aux = new LinkedList<Object>();
...
ListIterator<Object> listIterator = aux.listIterator();

// replace the for loop with while. just to make it easier, but can be done with for loop
while(listIterator.hasNext()) {
    ...
    listIterator.add(o);
    ...
}
```

If you replace your code with this, it should work.

Comment: I think that this is the right answer. Modifying the number of elements in a list while iterating isn't allowed.